# Can political science gauge quantitatively the strength of US global leadership?

Tags: united-states, political-theory, international-relations

From my perspective, the headline coverage of the direction of the US on the global stage is mostly pessimistic. But I want to see if that is actually justified. I concede it's not an easy undertaking, but humans can split the atom, surely if we're astute enough, we can avoid biases and other statistical pitfalls.

Of course, "Global Leadership" is somewhat nebulous, but to my surprise, there are still many variables that can serve as excellent proxies. The challenge is that it doesn't appear to be a clean-cut verdict one way or the other. Starting with the data points for America retreating from global leadership, there are many obvious, measurable data points that can be collected either as time series or simple count variables:

#### America retreating from global leadership

- Credibility (Syria redline, [pulling support from
  Kurds](https://www.rollingstone.com/politics/politics-news/why-trump-decision-abandon-kurds-syria-disaster-898493/))
- Strength of totalitarian opponents increased (tally data)
- Outcome of US military engagements (ISIS, demise of Afghanistan)
- Other countries filling trading partner vacuum (BRI / China in
  Africa/South America)
- Lack of education system reforms, like when US had Sputnik moment (spending data)
- Domestic instability (polarization, storm of capitol building)

But the story of allies being disappointed in American leadership goes back decades. Post WWII, Truman, Eisenhower all faced blowback. Even Reagan got flak for pulling out of Lebanon. So, perhaps, it's not that we have to live up to the gilded age of democracy spreading globally in the 1980s-2000s. There were plenty of leadership missteps contemporaneously and prior to that time. Instead, there's also compelling data that global leadership is trending upwards:

#### America increasing its global leadership

- Self-evident tech leader (global tech issuers choose US exchanges)
- Countries are still clamoring to get into NATO (tally data)
- Allies still eager to seek US military training operations (tally data)
- Allies willing fight in Iraq and Afghanistan for 10-20 years (attests to credibility)
- More recently, treasury producing minimum global corporate tax rate

It seems that such a nuanced and layered issue is too subjective to answer, however, all the bullet points above can easily be measured. The data is there.

### Question

So, provided we have quantitative measures similar to the above, can theory get us any closer to a quantitative measure of American Global Leadership?

Comment: Good question but hard problem. The world is complex with many moving parts. Power is not only what you can do but also what others let you get away with, so it even depends on what people think about reach other. Nobody has all the information. An estimation of something is useless without an estimation of an error. You'll likely not get comprehensive answers. Now if you had 20 PhDs in statistics, 10 years time, a computing cluster and money to buy all the necessary information...

Comment: *Leadership* is a biased term, suggesting that America is a positive force that others voluntarily follow - not that I want to dispute this, but objectively assessing something neutral, like *American influence* is easier. (Speaking of *American ingerence/dominance* would be equally biased).